# Java multithread and Thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I encountered a problem about java multithreading in my graduate project. There are two threads. Thread A will execute an endless loop. In the loop, thread A will do something if the variable ***simulationSwitch*** is true. The boolean variable, ***simualtionSwitch*** is set to false initially so thread A will be busy waiting until ***simualtionSwitch*** is set to true.

Thread B handles http requests and sets simulationSwitch to true when receiving an http request.

Here comes the problem puzzling me. Thread A won't detect the change of ***simulationSwitch*** and do its job. However, if thread A calls Thread.sleep() in its loop, it can do its job properly if ***simulationSwitch*** is set to true by thread B. I'm really confused and want to figure out the reason.

```
public static boolean simulationSwitch = false;

// Thread A
public void startSimulation() throws Exception {
    while(true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // without calling Thread.sleep(), thread A won't do anything even if simualtionSwitch is set to true
        while (simulationSwitch) {
            // do something 
        }
    }
}

// this function will be called when receiving a specific http request
public void switchOn(){
    simulationSwitch = true;
}
```

Comment: Because even though `Thread.sleep()` isn't required to have any memory semantics, it can have.

Comment: Can you not use a semaphore for the inter-thread signal?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure changes across threads are visible, `simulationSwitch` should be declared as `volatile`.

Without volatile, then the changes can still be visible in some circumstances but you can't rely on it.

Comment: It helps. Thank you!